Entity Framework Core - Nullable foreign key with empty referrence object after using .Include method
It is weird that the reference object is null even when corresponding refernce record actually exists. Here are the details.
// Model
public class ItemSoldPrice
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ItemId { get; set; }
    ...

    public ItemForSale Item { get; set; }
}

public class ItemForSale
{

    [Key]
    [Column("PKID")]
    public int LeadID { get; set; }

    //some other simple properties
}

//OnModelCreating setting
modelBuilder.Entity<ItemSoldPrice>()
    .HasOne(t => t.Item)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey<ItemSoldPrice>(t => t.ItemId );

//Query
public IList<ItemSoldPrice> GetItems(int amount)
{
    var list = DbContext.ItemSoldPrices
                  .Where(xxx && t.ItemId != null && t.Item != null)
                  .Include(t => t.Item)
                  .OrderByDescending(t => t.xxx).Take(amount).ToList();
    return list;
}

Table ItemSoldPrice.



Id
ItemId
Other Columns




67691
93686
xxxxxxxx



When ItemSoldPrice.Id=67691, there is acutally a corresponding item in database with ItemId=93686, but returned ItemSoldPrice.ItemId and ItemSoldPrice.Item are both null. Why does it happen?
The werid thing is if I don't include reference object in query, ItemSoldPrice.ItemId can be filled with correct value.
var list = DbContext.ItemSoldPrices
                 .Where(xxx && t.ItemId != null && t.Item != null)
                 .OrderByDescending(t => t.xxx).Take(amount).ToList();

Why .Include(t => t.Item) lead to null reference?

Can you also provide the ItemForSale class? With a correct setting of your classes you don´t need any modelBuilder Settings, because EF can configure it automatically.
Does it work when you just try:  DbContext.ItemSoldPrices.First(t => t.ItemId == 93686)

public ItemForSale Item { get; set; } whould be nullable as well

Hi @decius, thanks. I just added Model ItemForSale.

Hi @decius, I tried DbContext.ItemSoldPrices.First(t => t.ItemId == 93686). It turns out that one ItemForSale can be related with many ItemSoldPrice. I guess this may be the reason. I just want add one way configration inside ItemSoldPrice, do you know how to achieve this?

You should define your Entity model more clearly, like this:
public class ItemSoldPrice
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ItemForSale ItemForSale { get; set; }
    public int ItemForSaleId { get; set; }
}

And
public class ItemForSale
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ItemSoldPrice ItemSoldPrice { get; set; }
    public int ItemSoldPriceId { get; set; }
}

Now EF can figure out the relationship itself. No need for any other ModelBuilder Settings.

If I only want to add relationship inside ItemSoldPrice and not add anything inside ItemForSale, can I achieve that?

Why do you want to do that? :) You should configure the relationship completely. Of course you can do that with the modelBuilder - than you could get rid of the Id-fields and only having the Navigation Properties.
